# controller to controller - handle click to show/ hid div

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could someone tell me how to show/hide div in child html by clicking checkbox in parent html page

So fa, I've
**common-Controller.js**

```
$scope.showOffers = function(){
    $scope.offerModal = !$scope.offerModal;
}
```

**common-ControllerView.html**

```
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='offerModal' ng-click='showOffers()'/>
    <div ng-include='child-view.html' ng-if='offerModal'></div>
</div>
```

**child-view.html**

```
<p>Great.! you have this ABCD offers</p>
```

I don't know why the click event not working. is that anything I'm missing here or am doing it wrong

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I'm voting to close this post due to typo `function(){` instead of `function{`

Comment: @AlonEitan no i dont see any errors..!

Answer (score 0):

To show/hide `div`, you don't need to handle the `offerModal` with click. It's already [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel), value will be automatically bound(`two way binding`) to it. So try like the following

```
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model='offerModal'/> 
    <div ng-include='child-view.html' ng-if='offerModal'></div>
</div>


// In Controller

$scope.offerModal = false // default to false
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-mmf454?file=home%2Fhome.html)

Solution 2:

```
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' ng-click="showOffers()"/> Toggle
    <div ng-include='child-view.html' ng-if='offerModal'></div>
</div>

// Controller
$scope.showOffers = function() {
    $scope.offerModal = !$scope.offerModal;
}
```

Comment: thats my typo when posting my question here. but actual code has no typo

Comment: We can't assume right, I thought that was the issue. Anyway, I have updated the answer, Can you try with this

Comment: Yes, As you said click event i dont need it, since its completely another .html file i tried to access model value via $rootScope. Ok let me try your example

Comment: Hey @Naren, thanks for the heads up.. yeah.. as per your solution its working. but in my case i've to do that only via ng-click as per the requirement ..

Comment: No problem, Updated second solution.